# How to setup Postfix to send mail 'from' any_address@mydomain.com using Google Apps?

Tags: linux, php, email, postfix

I have a Postfix mail server set up. I have one account credentials entered in. The mail server is sending mail through the Google Apps mail servers. So in a postfix config file I have my gmail credentials as:

```
test@mydomain.com
mypassword
```

In my PHP application I use the mail() function to send mail.

Everything works, except no matter what I set the 'from' header address to, it ALWAYS says it is coming from test@mydomain.com.

I have used other setups where the email's 'from' header could be altered, so that I could have support@mydomain.com, noreply@mydomain.com, etc..

Any help would be greatly appreciated in how to set this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change that at the Postfix level. Postfix already does what you want. Google replaces the sender with the authorized account. This is a "feature" of Google Apps to disallow the forging of senders.

**Edit:**
If you don't change Google Apps, then you have to change Postfix' behavior.

In `main.cf` edit or add:

```
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_relayhost
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/smtp_relayhost_auth
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
```

in `/etc/postfix/sender_relayhost` put:

```
user1@mydomain.com          [aspmx.l.google.com]
user2@mydomain.com          [aspmx.l.google.com]
```

in `/etc/postfix/smtp_relayhost_auth` put

```
user1@mydomain.com      user1@mydomain.com:mypassword
user2@mydomain.com      user2@mydomain.com:hispassword
```

and so on.

Comment: Are you familiar with a way in Google Apps to change this? If not, how can I add more authorized accounts in Postfix? I only know how to set one account.

Comment: @donutdan4114 It is somewhere in the Google Apps help. Found it two weeks ago but lost the link.

Comment: @donutdan4114 Researched: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=22370

Comment: Will check out when I have power again, and see if this does what I need